# Get value of attribute in xml file with a variable

Tags: php, xml

I want to get a value in my xml file but it doesn't work.

In my xml file, I have something like :

```
 <global>
   <something>test</something>
   <i1>foo</i1>
   <i2>bar</i2>
 </global>
```

So I want to get the vaues of `<ix>` inside a for loop.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $xml->iterations+1; $i++) {
    var_dump($xml->somthing); //This works ! Displays "test"
    var_dump($xml->i.$i); //this doesn't work, displays nothing
    var_dump($xml->i1); //this works, displays "foo"
}
```

How should I do to consider the variable ?

Comment: not sure what XML parser you are using;

Comment: Try `$xml->{'i'.$i}`

Comment: Just to note: elements in your presented markup contains 0 attributes

Comment: @Bert Yeah! It works ! Could you add an answer please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use curly brackets to access object properties by string:

```
$xml->{'i'.$i}
```